# How to cast byte to enum?

Tags: java, c#, android, enums

I have an Enum below

```
public enum PTIModel {

    USA_52((byte) 0),
    USA_54((byte) 0),
    USA_56((byte) 0),
    FOR_52((byte) 0),
    FOR_54((byte) 0),
    FOR_56((byte) 0),
    ALL_T5((byte) 0),
    SPC_T5((byte) 0),
    USA_AQ((byte) 0),
    FOR_AQ((byte) 0),
    ALL_CV((byte) 12),
    Pro2((byte) 0),
    USA_72((byte) 16),
    USA_74((byte) 0),
    USA_76((byte) 0),
    FOR_72((byte) 0),
    FOR_74((byte) 0),
    FOR_76((byte) 0),
    USA_S4((byte) 0),
    USA_S6((byte) 0),
    FOR_S4((byte) 0),
    FOR_S6((byte) 0),
    SPECTRA_FLASHER((byte) 32),
    LastModel((byte) 0),
    AcceptorToolsV2((byte) 192),
    NotFound((byte) 254),
    BadFile((byte) 172);

    private final byte valuePTIModel;

    private PTIModel(byte value) {
        this.valuePTIModel = value;
    }

    public byte getValue() {
        return valuePTIModel;
    }
}
```

Now, In .Net they casting the byte value to enum like below.

```
private PTIModel getModel ()
        {
            byte b = 254;
            if (this._rawFile.Length == 131072) {
                b = (byte)~this._rawFile [130053];
            }
            else {
                if (this._rawFile.Length == 65536) {
                    b = (byte)~this._rawFile [62597];
                } else {
                    if (this._rawFile.Length == 64286) { //Added by Rivka
                        b = (byte)~this._rawFile [62597];
                    }
                }
            }
            if (b < 33) {
                this.TargetModel = (PTIModel)b;
            }
            else {
                b = 172;
            }
            return (PTIModel)b;
        }
```

And in the same way i am also trying to cast the byte value to enum in java. But, not able to do the same. How to do this? Below is my code..

```
private PTIModel getModel () {
        byte b = (byte) 254;
        if (this.mRawFile.length == 131072) {
            b = (byte)~this.mRawFile [130053];
        }
        else {
            if (this.mRawFile.length == 65536) {
                b = (byte)~this.mRawFile [62597];
            } else {
                if (this.mRawFile.length == 64286) { 
                    b = (byte)~this.mRawFile [62597];
                }
            }
        }
        if (b < 33) {
            this.mTargetModel = ??????;
        }
        else {
            b = (byte) 172;
        }
        return (PTIModel)b;
    }
```

Comment: whats the content of this.mRawFile and why you want to replicate same logic without understanding what they are doing?

Comment: mRawFile is a byte array.

Comment: And if you are understanding, please tell me what they are doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly of all, in Java you cannot cast from a primitive type to object type<sup>1</sup>.  That includes `enum` types.

What you could do is to write a method to *convert* a byte value to an instance of an `enum`.  However, in the Java example code you have shown us, the `valuePTIModel` values of the enum elements are not unique.  So the conversion is problematic.

If the `valuePTIModel` were unique, then you could use the following method to convert a byte to a `PTIModel`:

```
public static PTIModel convert(byte b) {
    for (PTIModel m : PTIModel.values()) {
        if (m.getValue() == b) {
            return m;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "invalid PTI model value (" + b + ")");
}
```

---

<sup>1 - The possible exception is when you "cast" an integral primitive type to one of the primitive wrapper classes.  But that is really a conversion too ... autoboxing ... rather than casting in the normal sense.</sup>